# JavaScript regex to standardize US zipcode

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't figure out whats what with a regex. The simplest reproduction is this failed match where I would expect that 3rd capture group to be 'A'.:

```
> console.log('00000-0000A'.match(/(\D)\s*(\d{5}-\d{4})\s*(\D)/g));
null 
undefined
```

Additional context includes:

```
const standardizeZipcode = (str: string) =>
  str
    .replace(/\b(\d{5})(\d{4})\b/g, "$1-$2")
    .replace(/(\d{5})\s*[-/ ]+\s*(\d{4})/g, "$1-$2")
    .replace(/(\D)\s*(\d{5}-\d{4})\s*(\D)/g, "$1 $2 $3");

test("inner whitespace", () => expect(standardizeZipcode("10001 - 1234")).toBe("10001-1234"));
test("multiple hyphens", () => expect(standardizeZipcode("10001 --- 1234")).toBe("10001-1234"));
test("no boundary", () => expect(standardizeZipcode("A00000- 0000B")).toBe("A 00000-0000 B"));
test("with boundary", () => expect(standardizeZipcode("A00000- 0000B")).toBe("A 00000-0000 B"));
test("spaces", () => expect(standardizeZipcode("A  00000- 0000 B ")).toBe("A 00000-0000 B"));
test("000000000", () => expect(standardizeZipcode("000000000")).toBe("00000-0000"));
test("00000000000", () => expect(standardizeZipcode("00000000000")).toBe("00000000000"));
test("00000-0000", () => expect(standardizeZipcode("00000-0000")).toBe("00000-0000"));
test("00000 0000", () => expect(standardizeZipcode("00000 0000")).toBe("00000-0000"));
test("00000 / 0000", () => expect(standardizeZipcode("00000 / 0000")).toBe("00000-0000"));
test("00000 / 00", () => expect(standardizeZipcode("00000 / 00")).toBe("00000 / 00"));
test("00000/0000A", () => expect(standardizeZipcode("00000/0000A")).toBe("00000-0000 A"));
test("00000/0000 B", () => expect(standardizeZipcode("00000/0000 B")).toBe("00000-0000 B"));
```

"00000/0000A" and "spaces" both fail, but you can see the the middle/hyphen regex is matching:

> - Expected   "00000-0000 A"
> - Received   "00000-0000A"
> - Expected   "A 00000-0000 B"
> - Received   "A 00000-0000 B "

It seems to be an issue with only the last replace/regex that attempts to ensure there is only one white space char before and after the zipcode.

How do I change .replace(/(\S)\s*(\d{5}-\d{4})\s*(\S)/g, "$1 $2 $3"); so that it matches on the two failed cases and not break the rest?

Comment: You can't expect `/(\D)\s*(\d{5}-\d{4})\s*(\D)/` to match `00000-0000A` because the first `\D` does not find any non-digit before the 5-digit substring.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, it might be caused by the `\D` which matches any character that is not a digit. So that might include white space.

Try `\S` which would which would match for any non white-space character instead. I would also use `.trim()` to remove any unnecessary white-space characters from the beginning or the end of the string.

Give this a try and let me know if that covers your use-case:

```
const standardizeZipcode = (str: string) =>
  str
    .replace(/\b(\d{5})(\d{4})\b/g, "$1-$2")
    .replace(/(\d{5})\s*[-/ ]+\s*(\d{4})/g, "$1-$2")
    .replace(/(^|\S)\s*(\d{5}-\d{4})\s*(\S|$)/g, "$1 $2 $3")
    .trim();
```

Using this, the test cases you provided pass.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the solution, here it goes:

```
const standardizeZipcode = (str: string) => {
    return str.replace(/\s/g, "")
      .replace(/\b(\d{5})(\d{4})\b/g, "$1-$2")
      .replace(/(\d{5})\s*[-/]+\s*(\d{4})/g, "$1-$2")
      .replace(/(\D)\s*(\d{5}-\d{4})(?!\d)/g, "$1 $2")
      .replace(/(\d)([A-Za-z])/g, "$1 $2")
      .replace(/(\/)/g, " $1 ");
}
```

Now the explanation: The first thing is to remove all white spaces to make your life easier:

```
str.replace(/\s/g, "")
```

Because you removed the white spaces, you need to add an new space when a number is found side by side with a letter (no boundary, with boundary, 00000/0000A and 00000/0000 B):

```
.replace(/(\d)([A-Za-z])/g, "$1 $2")
```

While testing, I noticed that standardizeZipcode("00000 / 00")).toBe("00000 / 00")) was not OK, so I used another replace to add spaces to both sides when the "/" is found.

```
.replace(/(\/)/g, " $1 ");
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The `\D` in your pattern not optional, and expects to match a single non digit.

You could use a single pattern with 4 capture groups optionally matching 1 or more characters other than a whitespace char or a digit at the beginning and the end.

Then you can make use of a callback checking for the value of capture group 1 and capture group 4:

```
^(?:([^\s\d]+))?\s*(\d{5})[/\s-]*\s*(\d{4})\s*(?:([^\s\d]+))?\s*$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xscb8s/1).

```js
const regex = /^(?:([^\s\d]+))?\s*(\d{5})[/\s-]*\s*(\d{4})\s*(?:([^\s\d]+))?\s*$/;

const replacer = (_, g1, g2, g3, g4) => {
  let result = "";
  if (g1 !== undefined) result += `${g1} `;
  result += `${g2}-${g3}`;
  if (g4 !== undefined) result += ` ${g4}`;
  return result;
}

const items = [
  "10001 - 1234",
  "10001 --- 1234",
  "A00000- 0000B",
  "A00000- 0000B",
  "A  00000- 0000 B ",
  "000000000",
  "00000000000",
  "00000-0000",
  "00000 0000",
  "00000 / 0000",
  "00000 / 00",
  "00000/0000A",
  "00000/0000 B"
].map(s => s.replace(regex, replacer));

console.log(items);
```